# On Android can a 3rd Party App access other apps notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

On Android can a 3rd Party App access other apps notification

What I am looking to do is to create an app that with a click will temporarily disable all notifications, and then with another click enable them back again. I dont want "do not disturbe" mode.

I am trying to create an app that will allow you to silence everything thats incoming and let you relax or focus on your work.

How would you guys do that? Any work around?

Comment: No, it's not possible for non-system apps.

Comment: Is there any work around? Even with the do not disturbe mode or something else?